# java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError invalid ELF header (Possible cause: endianness mismatch)

Tags: java, c#, c, java-native-interface

I have a C# dll and I'm consuming it in Java using a JNI bridge written in C which I have successfully done. The dll was built on Windows 7 32bit and runs on Windows 32 bit platform properly. I transferred the project to Ubuntu 64bit but I get the following error.

```
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: You have loaded library /projects/Glory DE 100/Debug/JNICsharpBridge.dll which might have disabled stack guard. The VM will try to fix the stack guard now.
It's highly recommended that you fix the library with 'execstack -c <libfile>', or link it with '-z noexecstack'.
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /projects/DLL/Debug/JNICsharpBridge.dll: /projects/DLL/Debug/JNICsharpBridge.dll: invalid ELF header (Possible cause: endianness mismatch)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:1941)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1824)
    at java.lang.Runtime.load0(Runtime.java:809)
    at java.lang.System.load(System.java:1086)
    at CsharpConsumer.<clinit>(CsharpConsumer.java:11)
```

My main objective is to develop a multi-platform solution. Somebody help me out.

Comment: Well, yeah.  DLLs are native to *Windows*, not Linux.  JNI is not magic.  On Linux, it helps you consume Linux shared libraries, which are in a completely different format. When you get native code involved, you compromise Java's cross-platform nature.

Comment: What do you recommend me to do so that i can achieve my goal?

Comment: If your goal is to consume your C# DLL via Java, then I recommend that you do it on a Windows machine.  If your goal is something else, then you'll need to clarify.

Comment: I have managed to consume C# dll in java. i want to run the same java code in Linux

Comment: I guess I did not say this explicitly enough: if you want to run the same Java code in Linux then you need to provide a Linux native library to support it, in place of the DLL that supports it on Windows.  Java on Linux cannot consume Windows DLLs, nor can Java on Windows consume Linux shared libraries.  Possibly you can get what you need by rebuilding your C# and C code on Linux (via Mono, for the C# part), but I cannot predict whether Mono will fully support your particular requirements.

Comment: @EnockN Hello Enock, all right? Let me ask you, have you managed to solve this problem? I'm going through exactly the same :(...

Comment: I ended up running it only in Windows.